# Double many-to-many relationship Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to implement a chat in my application, the database schema I created is:

[image]

When I generate my model with Entity Framework database-first, I got this :

[image]

I don't want to have User, User1, I want to keep From and To instead, when I change them directly in the model, I got error because the database and the model are not the same - how can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the default names of tables and columns that Entity Framework chooses for you, you can tell Entity Framework what they should be.

You can use attributes for this. IMHO this makes your code look horrible. Beside you can't use your classes in a different database with different names for tables and columns.

Therefore I prefer to use fluent API in `DbContext.OnModelCreating`

Let's first define classes User and Message

```
class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every User has zero or more "From" messages (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Message> FromMessages {get; set;}

    // every user has zero or more "To" message (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Message> ToMessages {get; set;}
}

class Message
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every Message has exactly one "From" user using foreign key FromUserId
    public int FromUserId {get; set;}
    public virtual User From {get; set;}

    // every Message has exactly one "To" user using foreign key ToUserId
    public int ToUserId {get; set;}
    public virtual User To {get; set;}
}
```

> In Entity Framework, the columns of your table are represented by non-virtual properties; the virtual properties represent the relations between the tables.

Hence, foreign keys are non-virtual, the items that the foreign keys point to are virtual.

Time to use fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var messageEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<Message>();
    // every messages belongs to exactly one User using foreign key `FromUserId`
    // every such User has zero or more From messages
    messageEntity.HasRequired(message => message.From)
                 .WithMany(user => user.FromMessages)
                 .HasForeignKey(message => message.FromUserId)
    // the same for To, using ToUserId:
    messageEntity.HasRequired(message => message.To)
                 .WithMany(user => user.ToMessages)
                 .HasForeignKey(message => message.ToUserId);
}
```

You could also do this the other way round, starting at Users:

```
var userEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<User>();

// every user has zero or more FromMessages (one-to-many)
userEntity.HasMany(user => user.FromMessages)
          .WithRequired(message => message.From)
          .HasForeignKey(message => message.FromUserId);
// every user has zero or more ToMessages (one-to-many)
userEntity.HasMany(user => user.ToMessages)
          .WithRequired(message => message.To)
          .HasForeignKey(message => message.ToUserId);
```

Comment: Hi Harald Thank you for your responce, i have two problems when do what you propose to me :
First : i put the code in OnModeleCreating() and he can't recognize the message.From and message.To.
Seconde : is that OnModeleCreating() is never called it is called only in code first, when i update the model from database it is not called at all, there is even and exception if ever it is called :

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }